# Question about $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(H_{2^k})^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, analytic-continuation

Define a function:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{{2^k}}\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(H_{2^k})^x} $$

where $H_k$ is the k-th harmonic number.

Questions:

1. For what values of $x$ is $f$ convergent?
2. Can $f$ be analytically continued?

I think $f$ converges for $\Re(x)>1.$ And I think it can be analytically continued but may not have a nice closed form in terms of known functions.

Comment: My numerical analysis suggests $$f(2)\approx2.286196176,$$ which is a number not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators. Note also that it is very hard to accurately compute many digits of $f(x)$ in the way it is currently given.

Comment: your sum is written as $$S=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{H_{2^n}^2},$$ where $H_m$ is the $m$-th Harmonic number. A hope for a closed form for this sum is unrealistic to say the least.